# How do you add a Widget area to the Wordpress search.php file?

Tags: wordpress, search, widget

We have build the default search of Wordpress to be for products only.  But we now want to add a left sidebar so customers can filter the results.

It looks to be via get_sidebar() in search.php, but that doesn't tell the system which Widget container to use.

How do we instruct it via the snippet of code?

We have looked into that get_sidebar() to see how you add code into it, but we cannot find any answers.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>


<?php
    if ( blade_grve_visibility( 'search_page_custom_header_title' ) ) {
        blade_grve_print_header_title('search_page');
    } else {
        blade_grve_print_header_title();
    }

    $search_style = blade_grve_option( 'search_page_style', 'masonry' );
    if ( 'grid' == $search_style) {
        $search_style = 'fitRows';
    }
    $columns = blade_grve_option( 'search_page_columns', '3' );
    $columns_tablet_landscape  = blade_grve_option( 'search_page_columns_tablet_landscape', '3' );
    $columns_tablet_portrait  = blade_grve_option( 'search_page_columns_tablet_portrait', '2' );
    $columns_mobile  = blade_grve_option( 'search_page_columns_mobile', '1' );
    $search_mode = blade_grve_option( 'search_page_mode', 'shadow-mode' );
    $gutter_size = 40;

    $search_extra_classes = '';
    if ( 'shadow-mode' == $search_mode ) {
        $search_extra_classes .= ' grve-with-shadow';
    }
?>

<!-- CONTENT -->
<div id="grve-content" class="clearfix">
    <div class="grve-content-wrapper">
        <!-- MAIN CONTENT -->
        <div id="grve-main-content">
            <div class="grve-main-content-wrapper clearfix">

                <div class="grve-section" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">

                    <div class="grve-container">
                        <!-- ROW -->
                        <div class="grve-row">

                            <!-- COLUMN 1 -->
                            <div class="grve-column grve-column-1">

                                <div class="grve-blog grve-blog-columns grve-isotope grve-with-gap<?php echo esc_attr( $search_extra_classes ); ?>" data-columns="<?php echo esc_attr( $columns ); ?>" data-columns-tablet-landscape="<?php echo esc_attr( $columns_tablet_landscape ); ?>" data-columns-tablet-portrait="<?php echo esc_attr( $columns_tablet_portrait ); ?>" data-columns-mobile="<?php echo esc_attr( $columns_mobile ); ?>" data-layout="<?php echo esc_attr( $search_style ); ?>" data-spinner="no" data-gutter-size="40">

                        <?php
                            if ( have_posts() ) :
                            $grve_post_items = $grve_page_items = $grve_portfolio_items = $grve_other_post_items = 0;
                            $grve_has_post_items = $grve_has_page_items = $grve_has_portfolio_items = 0;

                            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                                $post_type = get_post_type();
                                switch( $post_type ) {
                                    case 'post':
                                         $grve_post_items++;
                                         $grve_has_post_items = 1;
                                    break;
                                    case 'page':
                                         $grve_page_items++;
                                         $grve_has_page_items = 1;
                                    break;
                                    case 'portfolio':
                                         $grve_portfolio_items++;
                                         $grve_has_portfolio_items = 1;
                                    break;
                                    default:
                                        $grve_other_post_items++;
                                    break;
                                }
                            endwhile;
                            $grve_item_types = $grve_has_post_items + $grve_has_page_items + $grve_has_portfolio_items;

                            if ( $grve_item_types > 1 ) {
                        ?>
                        <div class="grve-filter grve-link-text grve-list-divider grve-align-left">
                            <ul>
                                <li data-filter="*" class="selected"><?php _e( "All", 'blade' ); ?></li>
                                <?php if ( $grve_has_post_items ) { ?>
                                <li data-filter=".post"><?php _e( "Post", 'blade' ); ?></li>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php if ( $grve_has_page_items ) { ?>
                                <li data-filter=".page"><?php _e( "Page", 'blade' ); ?></li>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php if ( $grve_has_portfolio_items ) { ?>
                                <li data-filter=".portfolio"><?php _e( "Portfolio", 'blade' ); ?></li>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <?php
                            }

                        ?>
                                    <div class="grve-isotope-container">
                                <?php
                                    // Start the Loop.
                                    while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                                        //Get post template
                                        get_template_part( 'templates/search', 'masonry' );

                                    endwhile;
                                ?>
                                    </div>
                        <?php
                                // Previous/next post navigation.
                                blade_grve_paginate_links();
                            else :
                                // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
                                get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );
                            endif;
                        ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Content -->
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer();

//Omit closing PHP tag to avoid accidental whitespace output errors.
```

We would like the search results page to have a left sidebar, with the Woocommerce filters, that current work within a Widget area called Single Portfolio.

Comment: According to your code, `search.php` already provides support for a sidebar (see the `get_sidebar();` call by the end of the file?) All that's left to do is to actually register a dedicated sidebar for the search results page using the [register_sidebar()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) function (assuming you haven't done so already) and then include it in your theme's `sidebar.php` file.

Comment: Thanks.  The developers of the theme came back to me, and told me it is not part of search.php.  They provided a javascript that somehow does it.  Thanks for your amazing help.  Happy to have this closed.